# How to use Guzzle to send API request to the Restful that supports only XML format?

Tags: php, xml, laravel, api, guzzle

I have been using Guzzle for a while within my Laravel 5.8 project. It has been working with Restful API that supports JSON format.

Now that there is a new Restful API that supports only `XML` format. I don't know how to do that using `Guzzle`. Below is an example of what the HTTP request might look like.

```
POST: http://api.url_endpoint.com/my_api.ashx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-url encoded
Host: http://api.url_endpoint.com
Content-Length: 467
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Close

<Section>
    <LoginDetails>
        <Login>ABC</Login>
        <Password>ABCDE</Password>
    </LoginDetails>
</Section>
```

In the documentation, it says: `The XML should be in the body of the request.`

Question 1. How do I put XML in the body of the request?

Question 2. Note the `HTTP/1.1`, should it be concatenated as suffix of the API URL endpoint?

This is how I have tried.

```
$header_options = [
    'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/xml',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-url encoded',
            'Host' => 'http://api.url_endpoint.com',
            'Content-Length' => 467,
            'Expect' => '100-continue',
            'Connection' => 'Close',
    ],
    'body' => '<Section><LoginDetails><Login>ABC</Login><Password>ABCDE</Password></LoginDetails></Section>',
];

$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://api.url_endpoint.com/my_api.ashx', $header_options);

dump($response->xml());
```

But I still get 400 Bad Request as response back.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try with just the fix of the Content-Type header value : `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (not `application/x-www-form urlencoded`).

If this does not work, also try to parse the body like that :

```
$header_options = [
    'headers' => [
            ...
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ...
    ],
    ...
    'body' => urlencode('<Section><LoginDetails><Login>ABC</Login><Password>ABCDE</Password></LoginDetails></Section>'),
];
```

If this does not work, could you try to change the header set that way :

```
$header_options = [
    'headers' => [
            ...
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml', // also try 'application/xml'
            ...
    ],
    ...
];
```

Let me know if one of these ideas helped you :)

Comment: From my example above, everything was correct, except that I should not include the `Host` element in the `headers`.